# What is the difference between dynamical and geometric phases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, schroedinger-equation, topology, poincare-symmetry

How can one differentiate between dynamical and geometric phase produced in the time dependent Schrodinger evolution of a quantum system? How we can describe or define these two terms separately?

Answer (score 9):

The total phase is a sum of the dynamical and geometric phases:
$$\phi = \int_0^T E(t) dt + \oint A_{\mu}(R) dR^{\mu}$$
Where $R^{\mu}$ are the coordinates of the parameter space, $E(t)$ is the instantaneous energy, and
$$A_{\mu} = i \langle \psi(R)|\nabla_{R}|\psi(R)|\rangle$$
is the Berry connection.

The dynamical phase (first term) depends on the state's Energy and the time that takes the system to complete a loop in the parameter space. The geometric phase (second term) depends on the direction of the eigenstate in the Hilbert space but not on the energy. Furthermore, it depends on the loop's geometry but not on the time; the same phase accumulates if the system had completed the loop slower or faster.

The two phase contribution combine additively, the combined phase generates a U(1) rotation of the final wave functions, measured for example in interference experiments.

The geometric phase encodes the state of the system, while the dynamical phase is very sensitive to the experimental setup. Thus in experimental measurements of the Berry phase, clever measures are taken to cancel the dynamical phase.

There are many techniques to achieve this purpose. For example [Sanders, de Guise, Bartlett, and Zhang](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0010068v2) describe a technique to generate a counter-propagating laser beam with an opposite polarization by means of a beam splitter. This beam accumulates the same dynamical phase but a geometric phase with an opposite sign. Thus when the two beams interfere, the dynamical phase cancels while the geometric phase doubles, allowing for its measurement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is quite helpful for me. But still there is something which I am not getting. If the combined phase generates U(1) rotation, then how can we say this by just looking at the final state after evolution that only the dynamical phase will be sensitive to the experimental setup.  (The final state looks like $|\psi_n (t)> = e^{i \theta_n (t)} e^{i \gamma_n (t)} |\phi (0)>$ with $|\phi (0)>$ as eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.)

Comment: You cannot say that just by looking at the final expression, however, in the specific application given in the reference (and in many others), the dynamical phase is an optical phase which is proportional to ratio the optical path which is a macroscopic number to the wavelength which is a very small number, thus it is huge. It is very difficult to manufacture the optical instrument in accuracy comparable to the wavelength. Thus a clever way to cancel the dynamical phase is to pass another beam through the same apparatus, in such a way that its geometric phase has an opposite sign.