# What kind of phase it is when a photon gain a quantum phase, a dynamical one or a geometrical one?

Tags: quantum-optics, topological-phase, foundations

It's known$^1$ that the phase factor in quantum mechanics can be divided into [geometric phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase) and dynamical phase. Since in quantum optics, light is treated as a quantum object, i.e., the photon. So the phase in quantum optics might also be divided into geometric phase and dynamical phase. To be more concrete, if a photon passes through the phase shifter, obtaining a phase $e^{i\theta}$, what kind of phase it is? The geometrical one or a dynamical one?

---

1. David Bar Moshe (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369735), What is the difference between dynamical and geometric phases?

Comment: What kind of phase shifter are you referring to?

Comment: In principle either, depending on how the phase shifter is made (it doesn't matter _how_ a phase shifter shifts phase, as long as it does it). But I think most of the time you'd call it a dynamical phase.

Comment: @LucasBaldo What about the usually used phase shifter in the MZ interferometer, Which can be described as $e^{i\hat{n}\theta}$?

Comment: @knzhou I can't see why most of the time it's a dynamical phase? Can you explain in more detail? Thanks!